# javaBegginer - how to counts from 10 to 0 using while/do while

Tags: java

I started learning Java and I can't solve this:

I want to code program which will be counting from 10 to 0 using "do while" and show numbers from 9 to 1.
I did this:

```
public class exWhile {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int a = 10;

        do  {        
            --a;  
            System.out.println(a);                

        }    while (a==1);

       }    
}
```

Why this wont working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is saying "while a equals 1" do stuff. Since a isn't initialized to 1, it's only going through the do-while loop once.

What you want to do is 
    while(a != 0) 
or you can also do 
    while (a > 0) 
to print 10 thru 0.

Answer (score 4):

The loop exits almost immediately after the first iteration since the exit condition has been met. Use

```
...
} while (a != 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is saying is to continue looping through prints while the value of a is one. You stay a at ten, so this is not true, and the loop exits.

You want to do something like this

```
While(a!=0){
System.out.println(a);
a--}
```

Comment: a bit late to the party :)

Comment: Beter late than never, eh?